# certificate invalid after publish asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, certificate, publishing

Im having trouble with my certificate which is required to communicate with a third party web service. When ever I run my application from VS everything works fine. When I publish this application to the IIS server and run it I get a certificate error. Its not an exception, its an error message from the third party service telling me the certificate is invalid. At some point in the publishing process the certificate is altered or something else, but I have no idea where, why or what to do.

Some extra info, just so you know this isnt the problem:

I had some other issues with the certificate after publishing, which was the IIS not being able to load it. This error gave me an exception when trying to create the request. This problem I fixed that by making the application pool load user profile.

**Edit**

I had to set application pool identity to localSystem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app in IIS. See if the certificate is properly installed - you may see something like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3a1db5d-d81b-4b9a-bd08-5b3b69b7e708/windows-cannot-verify-the-digital-signaturecode-52?forum=wdk)

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean ? Could you be more specific about where to look?

Comment: I'm not sure about how other versions look like but for [IIS 5 and 6](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4875/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-microsoft-iis-5-amp-6).

I've had this experience when my certificate's trusted publisher and root certification authorities were not properly setup.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit if I am to verify this isnt the problem.